# Different speeds for each line of text

Tags: javascript, parallax

I'm trying to do a parallax effect for many different divs with text. So every line will be at different speeds on scroll. I'm trying with this function but the lines do a 'jumpy' movement instead only scrolling at a slower speed. Am I missing something?
Thanks for any advice!

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  const target = document.querySelectorAll('.linea');
  var index = 0,
    length = target.length;

  for (index; index < length; index++) {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.speed*0.05;
    target[index].style.transform = 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)';
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="linea" data-speed="2"> line of text 1 </div>
<div class="linea" data-speed="1"> line of text 2 </div>
<div class="linea" data-speed="4"> line of text 3 </div>
```

Comment: Try logging `window.pageYOffset` when the scroll event occurs to the console and you'll see why it's jumpy! You need [easing](https://easings.net/)

Comment: The problem is that the line goes up with the normal scroll but then comes down a few pixels when the user stops scrolling. I just need that the speed of upward movement is slower (at different speeds) and stay in the same position when the user stops.